# A basic question on Stone-Cech compactification of $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: co.combinatorics, ultrafilters, gn.general-topology, stone-cech-compactification, fa.functional-analysis

Can the identity isomorphism on the additive group $\mathbb{Z}$ be extended to a non-identity semigroup isomorphism on $\beta\mathbb{Z}$, and still preserves $\beta\mathbb{Z}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$? Obviously this extension is discontinuous.

Comment: That might be a silly question but : what is the semi group structure on $\beta \mathbb{Z}$ ? as far as i know cartesian product of ultrafilter are no longer ultrafilter, so the sum of two ultrafilter has no reason to be an ultrafilter in general ?

Comment: If you are interested in algebraic structures on the compactification of a topological group (here the whole numbers as a discrete group) then I would suggest that perhaps you should look at the Bohr rather than the Stone-Cech compactification

Comment: There is a standard definition.  A set X is in U+V iff
{i in Z : {j in Z : i+j in X} in V} in U.  See Hindman and Strauss's book or either of the following books by Todorcevic: "Topics in Topology", "introduction to Ramsey Spaces."

Comment: I agree with Justin's suggestion to see the book of Hindman and Strauss, "Algebra in the Stone-Cech Compactification".  I suspect the answer to your question isn't known, but if it is (or, rather, if it was a few years ago) then this book would very probably contain it.

Comment: I have to disagree with jbc. The perspective "let's only look at compactifications which are groups" would ignore a whole bunch of interesting and actively studied semigroup compactifications (WAP and LUC being the obvious ones).

Comment: In response to Simon Henry: well, Safoura and I belong to the tradition that immediately shout "Arens products on the second dual of the group algebra". ;)

Comment: @Alvin, could you add some details as an answer for people who come across this in future?